# What shape results from this deformation of a circle?

Tags: geometry

Let's say we have a circle, but I want to "squish" the bottom half somehow. I decided to do it by altering the distance from the horizontal diameter to the bottom perimeter, by making it 2/3rds of what it would be if it was a perfect circle.

What shape results? Would it be an ellipse? (or half an ellipse since it's only the bottom half).

In case you're wondering, I came up with the idea when thinking about lifting bodies. This is supposed to be the cross section of a fuselage, and I wanted to make it look more like a simple airfoil.

Comment: it will be half of an ellipse.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are making the transformation $(x,y)\to (x,2/3y).$ Thus, the original circle $x^2+y^2=R^2$ is transformed to $$x^2+\frac{4}{9}y^2=R^2,$$ that is the equation of an ellipse. Since you are considering only the bottom half you get half of an ellipse. But, since the top half is not changed you get a figure that is half a circle and half an ellipse.

Comment: $ x^2+\dfrac{9}{4}y^2=R^2 ? $ ; the minor axis is smaller.

Comment: But the top and the bottom aren't squeezed equally (actually, the top half doesn't seem to be much changed at all), so it doesn't become an ellipse.

Comment: @Narasimham It is contracting the $y$-direction.

Comment: @Arthur I have edited the answer to consider this. In my opinion the OP is asking only about the bottom half.

Comment: Yes, I'm only changing the bottom half. The top half remains the same so it's a semicircle. Looks like the bottom half becomes a semi-ellipse. Thanks.

Comment: OK, that's better. But still, I feel like there should be a smoother, named curve out there that also works. That's just me, though.

Comment: The OP wants no continuous elastic curve. He is happy with reduced bottom half ellipse.

Comment: @Narasimham "Continuous" just means no breaks, no cusps, and no immediate direction changes in the line, yes? Since there are 2 points where y = 0, and they both coincide with the circle's and ellipse's equation, then this shape can be called continuous? If so I'm satisfied. I don't need an official name for a half-circle-half-ellipse.

Comment: BTW, the moon has this shape before and after full moon, each day has an official  name in the Indian calendar.

Comment: @Narasimham Oh wow didn't even realize about the Gibbous Moon! That should be the official name of this shape: gibbous circle!

Comment: @DrZ214. So whenever I look at the Gibbous moon I compute the visible/projected/bright area to be $ \pi/4 \cdot $ Big diameter$ \cdot $Small diameter ! And also for the famished crescent we take the difference :) !

Answer (score 1):

As I understand it is a second order discontinuous curve forced with curvature discontinuity at ends of horizontal  diameter.

Top half original
$$ x^2+y^2=R^2, $$

Bottom half squeezed
$$ (\dfrac {x}{R} )^2 + (\dfrac {y}{2R/3} )^2 =1  \rightarrow x^2+ 9 y^2/4 =R^2. $$
If the ellipse is to be flattened semi-minor axis should decrease, coefficient should increase compared to circle as given in the sketch.

[image: ProlateOblateEllipses]

Comment: I think u meant 4/9, but yes that would be the squeezing I want, and it turns out to be an ellipse.

Comment: No, I made no mistake.The minor axis is $ \frac23 R $ that you wanted.

Comment: Can you expound upon that in your answer? Either your or mfl's answer has a mistake. If you're thinking like y^2 = (2/3 R)^2 and then bringing it over as the inverse, it would actually have to be (9/4)(x^2 + y^2) = R^2

Comment: The sketch makes it clear.